# Закрыть окно другого класса

Tags: java, swing

Есть 2 класса.
В первом классе есть окно с кнопкой, во втором классе также окно с кнопкой, которая должна закрывать первое окно.
Так вот, как можно закрыть окно первого класса по нажатию на кнопку из второго класса? (вариант закрывать первое окно по нажатию на первую кнопку - не подходит)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы второе окно могло управлять первым, ему необходимо передать экземпляр первого окна. Тогда оно сможет сделать с первым что угодно:

```
class Win1 extends JFrame {
    ...

    public Win1() {
        ...
        newWindowButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            Win2 win2 = new Win2(this);
            ...
        });
    }
}

class Win2 extends JFrame {
    private Win1 win1;
    ...

    public Win2(Win1 win1) {
        this.win1 = win1;
        ...
        closeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Закрываем win1 любым известным способом. Например, так:
                win1.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(win1, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
                // Ну, или как-то так:
                win1.setVisible(false);
                win1.dispose();
                // Первый вариант эквивалентен нажатию на крестик в углу окна.
                // От второго отличается тем, что будут вызваны 
                // установленные обработчики события закрытия окна.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Экземпляр `Win1` можно передавать в `Win2` не только через конструктор, но и через сеттер, но через конструктор надёжнее, так как нет риска использовать его до установки значения.